# NPM install fails in dockerized env

Tags: git, docker, npm

I am trying to set up some legacy project with docker. To do so I have created a main repository with `docker` files and added actual project as a `submodule`. As a result I have:

```
root
|- data
|- etc
|  |-php
|  |-etc
|- project
|  |- .git
|  |- (actual project files)
|- docker-compose.yml
|- .dockerignore
```

In such setup the `project/.git` is just a text file containing `gitdir: ../.git/modules/project`.

Now, in `docker-compose.yml` I have following volume mapped:

```
- ${APP_PATH}:/var/www/html
```

Within this container I install `npm install` (I know I should prepare separate container for `node` and I will do it in the future but for now I need to run what I do have) and this ends up with following `git`

```
root@06fc2e3fe52a:/var/www/html# npm install
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/bengourley/stack-generator.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/project
```

I have already created following `.dockerignore` file:

```
project/.git
project/.gitignore
project/.gitattributes
.git
Dockerfile
.DS_Store
.gitignore
README.md
/tmp/*
```

Is it possible to make this work without mapping a root docker directory above the `www` in container so that this `npm install` could go through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make this work without mapping a root docker directory above the www in container so that this npm install could go through?

That might be a bit of a challenge, considering that within the `docker build` process, all Git-related folder are ignored (per your `.dockerignore` file).

> I'd really need an answer on how to handle npm install in connection with git subrepositories

That is what [`npm` issue 6700](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6700) is about.
It proposes several approaches:

> - a `postinstall` script to initialize your git submodules. As [in this example](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples)
> - checking out all the git repositories into parallel directories, e.g.,

```
src/
src/mod1
src/mod2
src/mod3
```

> and then use **`npm link`** to connect the dependencies:

```
$ cd src/mod1
$ npm link
# this makes a link from the system-wide node_modules to the current dir 
$ cd ../mod2
$ npm link mod1
# this makes a link from node_modules/mod1 to ../mod2
```

> That way if you make changes in mod1 or mod2, they can be committed to the appropriate git repository, and you can see the changes right away without having to re-install, re-download etc.
>
> - using the [`grunt-git` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-git)

The second approach is promising, provided you can mount a pre-initialized submodule repo into a separate path, and use `npm link` to reference the right folder while still being in `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem but could solve it with a `.dockerignore`-file.

```
src/.git
src/.gitignore
src/.gitattributes
```

but at the level of the Dockerfile (while src is the sub-repo), not on the top-level.